# Rails Photo Gallery Plugin for 3rd Party Hosting on Flickr or Picasa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, flickr, picasa

I don't want to store photos on the server. I'd prefer to use picasa or flickr, etc. I'm wondering what solutions are popular and work well. I've found:

- http://code.google.com/p/picasaonrails/
- http://code.google.com/p/loupe/

Has anyone tried these? Any alternative suggestions? Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For flickr you can use [flickr_fu](http://github.com/commonthread/flickr_fu/tree/master) or [flickr](http://github.com/ctagg/flickr/tree/master). You should also have a look at this [blog post](http://www.urbanpuddle.com/articles/2008/07/14/a-brief-intro-to-2-flickr-gems-for-rails-2-1).

Comment: FWIW, I actually ended up with rubyforge.org/projects/flickraw/ and lightbox_helper.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that most people will use S3 for this kind of storage. There is the amazon aws gem I think for doing this.

Comment: Well-taken railsninja -- but then it's not free ;) It's for a personal site.